# Python how to break

Tags: python

I have a code down here with try and catch and i want to break the code when the user write in exit
with the Kard variable but i tried to compare it but it failed!

```
print("MATHLETE 2.0")
print("-------------")

#Variabler
kard = 0
summan = 0
medel = 0
#svar = 'exit'
i = 0

while True:

    

    kard += 1
    summan = summan + kard
    try:
        kard = int(input("> "))
        
    except ValueError:
        if str(kard) == 'exit':
            break
        else:
            print("Fel - Ogiltigt Nummer")
            print("-------------")
        
       
        
summan = summan + kard
    
print("-------------")
print("Kardinalitet: ", kard)
print("Summan: ", summan)
print("Medelvärde: ", medel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when it throws exception on `kard = int(input("> "))`, the `str` value is never saved. Here is what you're looking for:

```
# ...
kard_str = input("> ")
try:
    kard = int(kard_str)
except ValueError:
    if kard_str == 'exit':
        break
    print("Fel - Ogiltigt Nummer")
    print("-------------")

# this line seems to belong to the loop, fix the indent:
summan = summan + kard
```

Answer (score 0):

When the exception is thrown, the program stops at `int(input("> "))`, and is unable to complete the assignment. So `kard` stores the value of whatever the previous valid input was.

The solution should be:

```
try:
  kard = input("> ")
  kard = int(kard)
except:
  if kard == "exit":
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("MATHLETE 2.0")
print("-------------")

#Variabler
kard = 0
summan = 0
medel = 0
#svar = 'exit'
i = 0
ex = False
while True:

    

    kard += 1
    summan = summan + kard
    kard = input("> ")
    try:
        kard = int(kard)
        
    except ValueError:
        if str(kard) == 'exit':
            ex = True
            break
        else:
            print("Fel - Ogiltigt Nummer")
            print("-------------")
        
       
if !ex:     
    summan = summan + kard
    
print("-------------")
print("Kardinalitet: ", kard)
print("Summan: ", summan)
print("Medelvärde: ", medel)
```

Try this one.

Comment: What is your `ex` variable for? Under what circumstances could the statements after the loop be reached when `ex` is `False`? Also what is `!`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to check entered data on whether it is number, rather then throwing an exception:

```
userInput = input("> ")
if userInput.isnumeric():
    kard = int(userInput)
elif userInput == "exit":
    break
else:
    print("Fel - Ogiltigt Nummer")
    print("-------------")
```

Answer (score 0):

it is my first answer and it is really my pleasure to meet you!
Well, i guess you want to ask "why int() doesn't work" right?  There are quite many limits and features in the source code of "int()", maybe you can try

> help(int())

and

> help(int)

for more information about "int()"
I hope it can be helpful, good luck!